# Slick 3.0.0 - multiple inserts depending on each other with return value

Tags: scala, slick

I'm trying to update to Slick 3.0.0 (reactive Slick), however I can't get the most basic stuff to work. Before I could just do something like `db.withTransaction { ... }` and it would run, however I can't even get this to compile:

```
def insertNewFacebookUser(
  facebookId: String,
  email: String,
  firstName: String,
  lastName: String
) = {
  val user =
  (Users.map(u ⇒ (u.email, u.firstName, u.lastName)) returning Users) +=
    ((email, firstName, lastName))

  FacebookAuths.map(f ⇒ (f.userId, f.facebookId)) += ((user.id, facebookId))

  user
}
```

This just complains that `user.id` is wrapped in some `DBIOAction`, how should I write this so it compiles?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without knowing more about the schema:

```
def insertNewFacebookUser(
  facebookId: String,
  email: String,
  firstName: String,
  lastName: String
): DBIOAction[???, ???, ???] = for {
      userId <- Users returning Users.map(_.id) += (email, firstName, lastName)
       _     <- FacebookAuths += (userId, facebookId)
    } yield (User(userId, email, firstName, lastName))

val user: Future[User] = db.run(insertNewFaceBookUser(....)
```

I'm not sure what the exact type of DBIOAction will be returned as it depends on your schema, hence the `???`. Everything is wrapped in an action of sorts so when you attempt to use the `userId` directly in the insert to FacebookAuths, it's the wrong type. Instead what you want to do is `map`/`flatMap` on the returned results and compose your fuller action. The `for {...} yield` is just sugar on `map` and `flatMap`. You then `run` your action to get a `Future` of your result. You can then `map` on that as you need to.

Comment: Thanks for a good answer! Now I understand more how to work with it. Thanks